# How do I make a number slowly return back to zero

Tags: java, math

Let me further explain my question. 
Let's say my Velocity is at -5.4028000 I would love it to return to zero like so.

```
-5.4,
-5.3,
-5.2
... 
-0.2,
-0.1,
0
```

Same with positive numbers. For them to return to 0, In groups of 0.1's. It would return to 0, every time it was run. Because this will be placed in a update loop.

Things I have tried:

```
if(vx > 0)
{
    vx-=0.1;
}
if(vx < 0)
{
    vx+=0.1;
}
```

But this just locks my VX into:

VX:0.04999999

OR

VX:0.09999999

Comment: Well what do you *want* to happen if you get a value greater than -0.1 and less than 0.1? Perhaps you should actually make the return proportional to the value, e.g. `vx *= 0.9;`

Comment: Sorry someone deleted their question. Yes I will try that @JonSkeet.

Comment: Nope, this is to do the with extend of the weird zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your number does not return back to zero is that the last subtraction may be subtracting a wrong number due to rounding errors. Since neither 5.4 nor 0.1 can be represented precisely in the format of `double`, your last subtraction (or your last addition in case of negative numbers) would "overshoot".

This is a problem for `Math.min(...)` and `Math.max(...)`.  Basically, we're going to only add or subtract the exact amount we need to reach zero.

```
if (vx > 0) {
    vx -= Math.min(0.1, vx);
}
if (vx < 0) {
    vx += Math.min(0.1, -vx);
}
```

Comment: Thank-you! This works amazing! And it is actually running very fast.

Comment: Won't work in the second case though - consider, if vx = -0.05 then Math.max(0.1, -0.05) will be 0.1. So, vx would become 0.05 and then get decremented by the first "if" next time round .

Comment: @BarrySW19 This is fixed now.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for the fix.

Comment: You can do it branch free using `vx -= Math.copySign(Math.min(0.1, Math.abs(vx)), vx);`…

Comment: For some reason @Holger your answer, actually works faster and smoother.

Comment: Couldn't this still get into the situation where imprecise doubles and double arithmetic makes it oscillate between two values?  This is more of a bandaid and only works with the exact value of `.1`.  Really, I think you want to set `vx=0` if `vx < .1` not do more substraction.  (I mean with a different double value  than .1)

Comment: @MaydonGameStudios Is it because you should use `else if` instead of `if`?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas You're making good points, but it's already been accepted as the answer so I don't want to make edits.  I think I would edit it to use `else`, or even change it completely to just explicitly set the value to 0 if it's within the range `-0.1 < vx < 0.1`.

Comment: @BenM. Hah, very true.  I wouldn't want to lose those 15 points either. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the final increment/decrement is not greater than the magnitude of the number:

```
if(vx > 0) {
    vx -= Math.min(0.1, vx);
}
if(vx < 0) {
    vx += Math.min(0.1, Math.abs(vx));
}
```

Comment: This works well too using Abs, to turn it positive.

Answer (score -1):

Well assuming you want a change rate of 0.1 per second and do not use any fancy library, you could do something like this:

```
while (Math.abs(vx) - 0.1 > 0.0) {
    vx += -Math.signum(vx) * 0.1
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
vx = 0.0;
```

Comment: Doesn't work - if vx starts as 0.15 the value oscillates forever between 0.05 and -0.05.

Comment: @BarrySW19 right, edited the answer to fix it.